# CDH 5.13.x spark gateway start failed

Tags: apache-spark, hive, cloudera-cdh

I have a problem when start the spark gateway in CDH 5.13.X using cloudera manager web UI.

Actually I want to run the hive on spark, so I follow the official docs which can be found [here](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/admin_hos_oview.html).

My CDH 5.13.x have 1 master and 4 slaves, and below is the spark service situation, History Server can run normally on the master, but the gateway can not.

---

[image: spark gateway]

---

when I choose to start one of the gateway service, it appears the error messages:

---

[image: error]

---

Anyone could help me? I am a newbie of spark and hadoop.